# POST method not working in swift 3.0 Alamofire 4.0?

Tags: ios, swift3

below are my parameters

```
 var comment: [String:AnyObject] = [:]
 comment  = [
            "txtUsername": (txtUsername?.text)! as AnyObject,
            "txtPassword": (txtPassword?.text)! as AnyObject
        ]
```

and post method function contains following code

```
Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

            for (key, value) in Param {
                multipartFormData.append((value.data(using: .utf8))!, withName: key)
            }

            let image = UIImage(named: "bodrum.png")!
            if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)
            {
                multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "file", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
            }

    },
        to: webpath,
        encodingCompletion:
        {
            encodingResult in

            switch encodingResult
            {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON
                    {

                        response in

                        guard case .success(let rawJSON) = response.result else {
                            return
                        }
                        guard let json = rawJSON as? [String: String] else {
                            return
                        }

                       if json["Success"] == "True"{
                            print("Success")
                        }
                       else{
                            print("Failure")
                        }
                    }

                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
            }
    }
    )
```

here in objective c my webservice work successfully but in using this code it always give response "false" ...Is there any mistake in this code.

Comment: Not sure if it solves the problem but in Swift 3 annotate `[String:Any]` – or omit the annotation since the dictionary is clearly `[String:String]` –  and delete the casts to `AnyObject`

Comment: Do you mean "Failure" is printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things can go wrong. There are a couple of things I would check if I were to debug:

1. If I want to use PNG, I might use `UIImagePNGRepresentation(...)` in this code instead of `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`.
2. If I want to use JPEG, I will change `multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "file", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")` to `multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "file", fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")`.
3. If (2), try changing `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)` to `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5)`. It could be failing because the image is too large, so applying higher compression might uncover the issue.

Comment: even if i not send image i only send parameters then also it not works